# Can I put verb and past participle as adjective?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, present-continuous

Is it correct to say:

> a first surface is **extending bent** from a second surface

This sentence is from patent context and I think the sentence means

> a first surface is extending from a second surface while being bent (the shape of the first surface is bent)

Comment: _The first surface extends and bends (or curves) from the second surface._

Comment: put *an* before 'extending'

Comment: That would make it ungrammatical.

Comment: You can say that, but I wouldn't know what you meant.  You could say something like 'The first surface is extending vertically from a second surface" but I have no idea what you mean by 'bent'.

Comment: Your question has gotten 3 votes to close at the moment. I think it's because nobody could figure out what you meant. I'd like to suggest adding the intended meaning of your sentence to your question. In any case, please don't get discouraged from the close votes. The votes were only meant as a request to improve (edit) the question.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to say with your sentence. It would also be helpful to have the complete sentence, not just one part of it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. I added some explanation and hope it might help you  understand the question.

Comment: By bent do you mean curved, or is it actually bent (ie at a sharp angle?).

Answer (score 2):

While a technical person will likely understand, it is better to avoid misinterpretation by rephrasing it.

Similar sentence examples:

> The ship was departing laden against a strong wind.
>   Caren stared puzzled at John.

The confusion in your sentence comes from the fact that "*bent*" (the Past Participle) is an homograph of the noun "*bent*".  Perhaps the word "*curved*" as suggested by 'user8543', can make the grammatical structure a bit clearer.  If there is a sharp corner in the "first surface", use "*angled*".

Another note, do you need to use Present Continuous?  It seems that Present Indefinite would be simpler

> a first surface **extends** bent from a second surface

And why is there '***a***' in front of "first surface"?